# Enable/Disable group of different JComponents at the same time

Tags: java, swing

[image]

I would want to enable/disable the entire row of JComponents at the same time. 
For example if i choose n°porte=3, i would want to enable the first, the second and the third row and disable the last. I would want to avoid to disable/enable one Jcomponent at a time

Comment: Could you be more specific? Like adding the code that adds the components to the container.

Comment: *"I would want to avoid to disable/enable one Jcomponent at a time"* somehow each individual Component must be changed. If *you* refuse to do it, who do you think will? But of cause you should do this in some kind of loop...

Comment: If each row is inside, say, a JPanel, you can subclass JPanel with a method that enables/disables all contained components (I haven’t tried, but I wouldn’t expect disabling the JPanel itself would suffice — you may try).

Answer (score 1):

> I would want to avoid to disable/enable one Jcomponent at a time

Well there is no method that allows you to disable/enable a panel (and its components).

All you need to do is create a custom panel with a `setComponentsEnabled(boolean enabled)` method. Then you invoke this method as required.

You can use the `Container.getComponents(...)` method and then loop through each component to disable/enable them.

You can check out [Disabled Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/disabled-panel/) for an implementation of the above approach.